# Typescript - Give type info to AND extract type info from same object

Tags: typescript

Say I'm working with sound designers and want them to get good information while editing configuration files.
I think @eventsA below works fine for that purpose.
But then I would also like to get good type information in the rest of the application from those configs for the devs, and then I think @eventsB works well.
How can I get the best of both? That is errors when editing config files AND be able to extract specific types from the configs for use within the rest of the application.

```
interface IEvent {
    id: string
    actions: Array<{
        func: "setMasterVolume" | "playSound",
        args: Array<string | number | boolean>
    }>
}

// With type that is helpfull for sound designer
const eventsA: Array<IEvent> = [
    {
        foo: "bar", // this line will give error to sound designer because not in interface
        id: "start",
        actions: [
            {
                func: "setMasterVolume",
                args: [ 1 ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "stop",
        actions: [
            {
                func: "setMasterVolume",
                args: [ 0 ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

// This only gives unspecific 'string' type
type AudioEventsA = typeof eventsA[number]['id']

// With type that is helpfull for developer
const eventsB = [
    {
        foo: "bar", // now no error on this line unfortunately
        id: "start",
        actions: [
            {
                func: "setMasterVolume",
                args: [ 1 ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "stop",
        actions: [
            {
                func: "setMasterVolume",
                args: [ 0 ]
            }
        ]
    }
] as const

// Now I can extract type of: 'start' | 'stop' rather than just string.
type AudioEventsB = typeof eventsB[number]['id']
```

So how to get both error at: foo: "bar" and get `AudioEvents = 'start' | 'stop'`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2491m) meet your needs?  There is no `satisfies` operator in TypeScript (as requested in [ms/TS#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481)) so you need to write a helper function if you want.  Your requirement to prohibit excess properties complicates matters, but it's still doable.

Comment: Impressive, this is very close! I still cant extract more specific type than string from eventsA[number]['id']. But after reading the issue you posted I don't think it is possible at the moment.

Comment: Oh it is possible, I was just having trouble prohibiting excess properties in an ergonomic way (e.g., where only the excess property is in error and not the whole array) while maintaining the string literal props.  Try [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NValvw) and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Oh boy it does indeed work with your fix that's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could make your interface accept the expected types as `generics`. And since you allow your developers to create arrays with `const assertions` you have to tpye your arrays as `readonly`. To specify what types of arrays your developers are allowed to create you can create the type `Iarr` and they pass it the types they decide they are gonna need for their arrays.

```
export type Func = "setMasterVolume" | "playSound";

interface IEvent<T extends string, F extends Func, A extends string | number | boolean> {
    id: T
    actions: readonly{
        func: F,
        args: readonly A[]
    }[]
}

export type Iarr = readonly IEvent<'start'|'stop', "setMasterVolume", number>[];

// With type that is helpfull for sound designer
const eventsA: Iarr = [
    {
        foo: "bar", // this line will give error to sound designer because not in interface
        id: "start",
        actions: [
            {
                func: "setMasterVolume",
                args: [ 1 ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "stop",
        actions: [
            {
                func: "setMasterVolume",
                args: [ 0 ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

// This only gives unspecific 'string' type
type AudioEventsA = typeof eventsA[number]['id']

// With type that is helpfull for developer
const eventsB: Iarr = [
    {
        foo: "bar", // now no error on this line unfortunately
        id: "start",
        actions: [
            {
                func: "setMasterVolume",
                args: [ 1 ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "stop",
        actions: [
            {
                func: "setMasterVolume",
                args: [ 0 ]
            }
        ]
    }
] as const

// Now I can extract type of: 'start' | 'stop' rather than just string.
type AudioEventsB = typeof eventsB[number]['id']
```

Comment: That is the thing I don't know that will be only start and stop, the designers will add there own ids to the array of events, and the events will be different depending on each specific application.

Comment: @jadujoel ok, I edited the code. please have a look

Comment: Thank you it's a good workaround, it would be nice to not have to give the input of possible id's as the input to the IEvent generics. But I think one would need the 'satisfies' operator in typescript as @jcalz suggests for that.